# Parsing returned Json with native swift

Tags: json, swift

When hitting an API I get this blob of Json back, example below

```
{
  “item1” : 1234,
  “item2” : 4567,
  “item3” : “78910”,
  “item4” : “1234”
}
```

There is not much structure to it, I just want to know how to parse through in swift,

Here is the bottom of the code grabbing it (skipped over the url and request stuff)

```
let JSONObject: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil)


            if (JSONObject != nil) {
                // process jsonResult
                println("\(JSONObject)");


            } else {
                // couldn't load JSON, look at error
            }
```

The json prints to console fine in the format above, just wandering now how I can parse over and extract each item

The whole swift json thing looks a bit of a mess at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more neat way to do it, would be like this:

```
let json = "{\"item1\" : 1234, \"item2\" : 4567, \"item3\" : 78910, \"item4\" : 1234}" // simulated string response ...
let data = json.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true) // turn it into NSData
if let JSONObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: nil, error: nil) as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{
    println(JSONObject["item1"]) // prints Optional(1234)
}else{
    println("error")
}
```